# Finding the area of a triangle when only a the shaded part and two sides are known

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image: The problem is linked here]

I tried finding the height of the shaded triangle, which I calculated to be 5. Then I tried solving for the area of the non-shaded triangle, and I got 10 as my final answer. Am I correct?

[image: Here is my work]

Comment: Maybe if you showed your work, somebody might be able to point out any problems. Heck, *you* might be able to find out any problems. Also, links to images are discouraged: please inline the image.

Comment: Okay. I will do that

Comment: All you need here is the fact that the area of a triangle is half the product of base and height. You have enough information to find the height and you know the base of the second triangle. Voila!

Comment: So, is my work correct?

Comment: see that 6*h=15, extract the height and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: 10 is correct .........

Answer (score 1):

The ratio of the area of two triangles that share the same height is the ratio of the two bases.

We know the area of the unshaded triangle (which is $15$ square units) and the base of the triangle that has that area (which is $6$). As for the other triangle, we know its base length ($4$) but we don't know, and are solving for, its area.

Set up a proportion and solve for the unknown area.

(If anyone has other suggestions or corrections for my solution, please feel free to let me know.)